# Double-tap zoom & hammer.js issue

Tags: javascript, ios, hammer.js

Please could someone advise me on the following:

I have an image that when double-tapped or pinched-out should display an overlay.

I have used hammer.js which successfully carried out the pinch-out showing the overlay.
I have used double-tap in hammer.js to trigger the overlay however this does not work because the native iOS double-tap to zoom occurs. So instead of showing the overlay it zooms into the image I tapped on.

Does anyone know how I can stop this issue on the image so I can get hammer.js to open the overlay?

Answer (score 0):

Seems too late to answer, but still thought might help someone.
What I understand from the question is, there must be default tap gesture that is getting precedence. 
You can try this:

```
   if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
```